# How to use model attribute value in behavior config Yii

Tags: php, yii, model, behavior

I want create `ImageBehavior` for uploading and saving images. My behavior have two fields: `imagePath` and `imageField`. In my model i'm wrote:

```
public function behaviors(){
    return array(
        'imageBehavior' => array(
            'class' => 'ImageBehavior',
            'imagePath' => 'images/avatar-pics/'.$this->user->username,
            'imageField' => 'avatar',
        ),
    );
}
```

but this doesn't worked - i receive path -

> images/avatar-pics//image.png

What a solution? Create in behavior field `imageFolder` and add to config `'imageFolder' => 'user->username'`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering own question, but almost two years later build correct vision to this issue:

1) don't use line

> 'images/avatar-pics/'.$this->user->username

in your behavoir - it throws a notice "Trying to get property of non-object" - good application doesn't thows notices and warnings.

2) all you need is use

```
'images/avatar-pics/' . CHtml::value($this, 'user.username')
```

instead. If $this->user is null, value method returns null, so be sure that you have related user to your model.

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion:

Change the way you use your behavior and add some codes to your models. Take a look at the following example:

For example, your `behavior`:

```
class ImageBehavior extends CBehavior {
    public $imagePath;
    public $imageField;
    public function getImagePath() {
        return $this->imagePath;
    }
}
```

Your `model`:

```
class TestModel extends CFormModel {

    private $imagePath = '/home/x/y';

    public function setImagePath($imagePath) {

        $this->imagePath = $imagePath;
        $this->attachBehaviors(array(
            array(
                'class' => 'ImageBehavior',
                'imagePath' => $this->imagePath
            )
        ));
    }

    public function init() {
        $this->setImagePath($this->imagePath);
        parent::init();
    }

}
```

Now, take a look at tests and results:

```
$model=new TestModel();
CVarDumper::dump($model->getImagePath()); //output: /home/x/y

$model->setImagePath('/home/x/path2');
CVarDumper::dump($model->getImagePath()); //output: /home/x/path2

$model->setImagePath('/home/x/path3');
CVarDumper::dump($model->getImagePath()); //output: /home/x/path3
```

By this way, if you do not set any `imagePath` it uses model's default value. In front, each time you change the `imagePath` your path will change in your behavior.

Note: This is just a suggestion. By this, you can customize your `setImagePath` method to get the value from everywhere you want(another model, session and so on...).

Answer (score 0):

```
//inside the behavior:
$this->owner->user->username;
```

$this->owner - it's your model. Behavior is initialized before filling attributes, and the attribute value can be get only after the initialization.

Comment: Bad solution. For one model this way is work, but for another? In second model i need to set `'imagePath' => 'images/help/'.$this->id` - i lose flexibleness.